# How do ParseKit's Assembler Callbacks work? Where should I store the work I do in them?

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

How should I use callback functions in parsekit? suppose I have the following rule:

```
expr_s = expr_p '+' expr_s | expr_p ;
```

should I pop 3 symbols from the resulting PKAssembly and add first and last numbers and then push the answer back to the stack?
And for the above rule how should I know it is the first or the second rule that caused a match?
I don't understand the order in which ParseKit calls callback functions. I could really use some help.

Thanks Todd for your response, keeping in mind your instructions I wrote the following grammar and callback functions for a simple mathematics expression that includes addition and multiplication:

```
- (IBAction)press_equals:(id)sender {
NSString *g = @"@start = expr_s; expr_s = expr_p ('+'! expr_p)+ ; expr_p = Number ('*'!     Number)+  ;";
PKParser *p = [[PKParserFactory factory] parserFromGrammar:g assembler:self];
NSString *s = @"3*4+4*8";

[p parse:s];

PKAssembly *res = [p parse:s];
NSLog(@"res %@", res);

}



- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchExpr_s:(PKAssembly *)a {
NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

NSArray *toks = [a objectsAbove:nil];


double total = 0.0;
for (PKToken *tok in toks) {
    total += tok.floatValue;
}


a.target = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:total];
}
- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchExpr_p:(PKAssembly *)a {
NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

NSArray *toks = [a objectsAbove:nil];


double total = 1.0;
for (PKToken *tok in toks) {
    total *= tok.floatValue;
}
a.target = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:total];
}
```

and here is the output I get:

```
2012-04-06 22:54:31.975 Calculator[1070:207] -[CalculatorViewController    parser:didMatchExpr_p:] [3, 4]3/*/4^+/4/*/8
2012-04-06 22:54:31.976 Calculator[1070:207] -[CalculatorViewController parser:didMatchExpr_p:] [4, 8]3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
2012-04-06 22:54:31.977 Calculator[1070:207] -[CalculatorViewController parser:didMatchExpr_s:] []3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
2012-04-06 22:54:31.977 Calculator[1070:207] -[CalculatorViewController parser:didMatchExpr_p:] [3, 4]3/*/4^+/4/*/8
2012-04-06 22:54:31.978 Calculator[1070:207] -[CalculatorViewController parser:didMatchExpr_p:] [4, 8]3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
2012-04-06 22:54:31.978 Calculator[1070:207] -[CalculatorViewController parser:didMatchExpr_s:] []3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
2012-04-06 22:54:31.979 Calculator[1070:207] res 0
```

Why is my res 0?

Comment: Sadegh, I have updated my answer below to match your revised question. In the future, please consider starting a new question if the details of what you are asking change significantly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

First, the best way to understand this stuff is [Steven Metsker's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201719622), upon which ParseKit is based.

---

Second, checkout [my answer to another question about `PKAssembly`'s `stack` and `target`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098051/34934)

---

Third, here's [my answer to another PaseKit question about unexpected callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6237800/34934).

---

Fourth, checkout the [`TDArithmeticParser.m` file](http://code.google.com/p/parsekit/source/browse/trunk/test/TDArithmeticParser.m) in the the ParseKit **Tests Target** (included in the ParseKit Xcode project. This class has callbacks which implement the same kind of arithmetic logic you seem to be looking for.

Also checkout the [`arithmetic.grammar` file](http://code.google.com/p/parsekit/source/browse/trunk/res/arithmetic.grammar) (also in the ParseKit Tests Target). This is an example of how to design an arithmetic grammar in ParseKit syntax.

---

Finally, here's some thoughts more specific to your example above.

Let's clarify your grammar a bit, as the question you're asking is pretty basic, and I don't think it requires a very complex grammar to tackle. Here's a basic arithmetic grammar which gives multiplication and division operators precedence over addition and subtraction:

```
@start         = expr;
expr           = term (plusTerm | minusTerm)*;
term           = factor (timesFactor | divFactor)*;
plusTerm       = '+'! term;
minusTerm      = '-'! term;
timesFactor    = '*'! factor;
divFactor      = '/'! factor;
factor         = Number;
```

That `!` after the `'+'` tells ParseKit to **discard this token automatically**. This makes things slightly more convenient for you when writing your callbacks.

**Note** that if you want your grammar to have only left-to-right operator precedence (like a calculator), this grammar will not work. If you need that, please ask a separate question tagged #ParseKit here on StackOverflow, and I will answer it promptly.

I would define these callbacks:

```
- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchExpr:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

    NSNumber *n = [a pop];

    // the expr is complete, and its value is on the stack.
    // important! wrap things up by 
    // storing your work in `a.target`. not in an ivar.
    a.target = n;
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchFactor:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

    // a number token was found. store its number value on the stack
    PKToken *tok = [a pop];
    [a push:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tok.floatValue]];
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchPlusTerm:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

    // a '+' expr was found. pop off the two operands and add them
    // store the result on the stack temporarily
    NSNumber *n2 = [a pop];
    NSNumber *n1 = [a pop];
    [a push:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[n1 doubleValue] + [n2 doubleValue]]];
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchMinusTerm:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

    // a '-' expr was found. pop off the two operands and subtract them
    // store the result on the stack temporarily
    NSNumber *n2 = [a pop];
    NSNumber *n1 = [a pop];
    [a push:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[n1 doubleValue] - [n2 doubleValue]]];
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchTimesFactor:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

    // a '*' expr was found. pop off the two operands and multiply them
    // store the result on the stack temporarily
    NSNumber *n2 = [a pop];
    NSNumber *n1 = [a pop];
    [a push:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[n1 doubleValue] * [n2 doubleValue]]];
}

- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchDivideFactor:(PKAssembly *)a {
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, a);

    // a '/' expr was found. pop off the two operands and divide them
    // store the result on the stack temporarily
    NSNumber *n2 = [a pop];
    NSNumber *n1 = [a pop];
    [a push:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[n1 doubleValue] / [n2 doubleValue]]];
}
```

**Two important points** are

1. **Don't worry about how many times these callbacks are called**. They may be called more times than you expect, or in strange-seeming order.
2. **Don't store the results of work done in these callbacks in an ivar**. Always store your work on either the `a` argument's `target` or `stack`. I usually store temporary values on the `stack`, and the ultimate result on the `target`, as I find that most convenient. But you have flexibility there.

I would write this driver code:

```
NSString *g = .. // fetch grammar above
PKParser *p = [[PKParserFactory factory] parserFromGrammar:g assembler:self];
NSString *s = @"3*4+4*8";

PKAssembly *res = [p parse:s];
NSLog(@"res %@", res);
```

I see this log output:

```
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchFactor:] [3]3^*/4/+/4/*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchFactor:] [3, 4]3/*/4^+/4/*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchTimesFactor:] [3, 4]3/*/4^+/4/*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchFactor:] [12, 4]3/*/4/+/4^*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchFactor:] [12, 4, 8]3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchTimesFactor:] [12, 4, 8]3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchPlusTerm:] [12, 4]3/*/4/+/4^*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchPlusTerm:] [12, 32]3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchExpr:] [3]3^*/4/+/4/*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchExpr:] [12]3/*/4^+/4/*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchExpr:] [16]3/*/4/+/4^*/8
-[DebugAppDelegate parser:didMatchExpr:] [44]3/*/4/+/4/*/8^
res 44
```

Hope this helps.